# - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target. CocoaPod Swift3 pod update error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I've been running into a couple of strange errors in terminal when updating cocoapods after updating a Switf2 project to Swift3. Here are the errors:

```
[!] The `MyShowGuide [Debug]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyShowGuide/Pods-MyShowGuide.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `MyShowGuide [Release]` target overrides the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyShowGuide/Pods-MyShowGuide.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

So far I've tried numerous ways to try and remedy the issue including deleting derived data and running `pod deintegrate/ pod install`.  I also added `$(inherited)` to the  `Other Linker Flags` and `Header Search Paths` but still get the error.

Comment: Do exactly what it suggests.  Go into the Build Settings for  "Framework Search Paths" and change the value for your target to be "$(inherited)".  Why are you messing with "Other Linker Flags" and "Header Search Paths"?  (You probably want $(DEVELOPER_FRAMEWORKS_DIR) in there as well as $(inherited))

Comment: Thanks that worked, in plain sight.

Comment: There is no menu called "Framework Search path". Can you check if the answer needs to be updated in case of new versions?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

1. Target - > building settings- >`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`, Value type is Boolean, click on the other, change the value to
   `$(inherited)`
2. perform - pod update
3. Done

Comment: what should we set for "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES"  ?

Comment: These are for the secondary targets, correct? The ones that get the warning.

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5981#issuecomment-363591574

1. Go to Build Settings
2. Search for "Runpath Search Paths".
3. Double click the value field and add `$(inherited)`
4. Product -> Clean Build Folder

Run the cocoapods command in the terminal and things should go fine this time.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked. I also had to add to the Header Search Paths. Then clean and pod install again

Answer (score 5):

1. Target - > build settings- > BuildOptions-> Validate Build Product, Here the Debug value type is Boolean, Click here to change the value No to YES
2. Perform - Build Clean
3. Done

Comment: The correct answer is in the comment by @Tibrogargan in the comment below the question. I am not sure how your proposed solution would fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to iOS development, but the only thing that worked for me - is adding `$(inherited)` to the Linker Flags as described here https://mokacoding.com/blog/cocoapods-the-inherited-flag/

P.S. The iOS project was originally created from React Native template.

[image: Build Settings > Other Linker Flags section.]

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had deleted literary search path while solving another error so
i just clicked **debug** and pasted `$(inherited)` the i clicked **release** and again pasted `$(inherited)`
you can probably do the same for other fields and this is what is being told in the error message as well i.e use the `$(inherited)` flag
After this just do `pod update`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the accepted answer didn't fully work. I had to add `$(inherited)` to the Project itself and **both** build tests.

[image]

In short, just click all 3 places where the red arrows are pointing, and follow the same directions.

`Building Settings` > `All` > in the search box enter `ALWAYS EMBED SWIFT STANDARD LIBRARIES` > click on the `NO` > click `Other...` in the box that opens paste `$(inherited)` then press the return key.

You have to do this 3x total. One for each place where the red arrows are pointing.