# What's ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES with CocoaPods, Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

after installing cocoapods and adding `pod "SwiftCarousel"` to pod file and uncomment the platform :ios, '9.0' I got this ERROR

> ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES

and what should I do?

```
mohammed.elias$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing SwiftCarousel (0.8.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `scrollView.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

[!] The `scrollViewTests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-scrollViewTests/Pods-scrollViewTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `scrollViewTests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-scrollViewTests/Pods-scrollViewTests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `scrollViewUITests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-scrollViewUITests/Pods-scrollViewUITests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `scrollViewUITests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-scrollViewUITests/Pods-scrollViewUITests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
```

Comment: ```- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.``` — do either one of those.

Comment: d= (-_- ) Pretty old by now, anyone no longer supporting `iOS 12.1` or earlier [read related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365318/8740349)

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799712/4833705

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Go here in your build settings...

[image]

And then highlight the "Always embed..." row and hit delete. This will change it to use the inherited property.

Even after you make this change it will remain there but it will probably change from **bold** to normal text. If that change happens then it is inherited.

Normal text = inherited.

**Bold text** = overridden.

Comment: I hit delete and nothing changed.
could you be more specific , please ?
I'm very new to iOS devlopment.

Comment: It will remain there but it will prob change from bold to normal text. If that change happens then it is inherited. Normal text = inherited. Bold text = overridden.

Comment: Good , then should I do it for every project I'll make or there's a global configuration for Cocoapods ?

Comment: @Fogmeister for better visualisation of inheritance he also can select `Levels` option. It's way more visual than checking boldness of a text.

Comment: This was super helpful, it was silly hard to find that setting.

Comment: Simple and effective!

Answer (score 66):

I was able to fix this problem by doing the following (step by step):

1. Go to Build Settings
2. At the top select All and Combined
3. Under Build Options you should see Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries and it is bold.
4. Click on it and click delete (<-). It should now be unbolded. (Normal text = inherit)
5. Pod install and the error/errors should go away!

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me, are these errors or warnings? i am new , although the pods installed completely: "[!] The `LearningTests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-LearningTests/Pods-LearningTests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target." , is this a warning or error? is the pods install successfully?

Comment: @ArgaPK Yes exactly, follow their instructions and they'll go away

Comment: worked for me, for all those still getting errors, make sure to do this to the Targets OS and UITests also!

Comment: Can't delete on Xcode 11. Well, hitting on Delete just make it not bold, but doesn't actually delete the property.

Comment: Been a while, but pretty sure I was just hitting on the Delete button.

Answer (score 27):

1. Go to Build Settings
2. At the top select All and Combined
3. Under Build Options search "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries"
4. Update its value with $(inherited)
5. Now install pod and all the error should go.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

The accepted solution works, but now you have to make sure all of your teammates are performing it each `pod install`.

And we all know they won't.

You could make CococaPods do it automatically, by adding this to the bottom of your `Podfile`:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if config.name == 'MyPOD' 
                config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'Yes'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

More info here: https://www.devsbedevin.net/cocoapods-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries/

Answer (score 15):

I suggest to set all pods after install as suggested in the message:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = '$(inherited)'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It worked for me at the time. Cocoapods evolved since then ;)

Comment: 2022 here and it still works. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. **Delete** your Pods folder
2. set the ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES to *$(inherited)*;
3. run *pod install*