# XCode 8.3 Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: swift, xcode8

I started getting this error only after upgrading from XCode 8.2 to XCode 8.3, and only when making an archive build (debug builds work fine).

I think " if I will pod install again ? " then, a lot of err borned. do you know what going on ?

[image]

Comment: Solving pod warnings worked for me check the below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570233/whats-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries-with-cocoapods-swift-3-and-xcode

Answer (score 10):

Here also like as same linker command Issue in Xcode 8.3.1,

linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ans: Goto "Build settings" -> Target -> Set "Enable Bitcode" = NO.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: i tried everything, even i cleaned Derived Data folder but error is still there .

Answer (score 2):

Check if your project has a .xcworkspace file. If it does you should open that instead of the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: @LukášHejtmánek The .xcworkspace will include some dependencies that are needed in the project. e.g. some pods like the firebase library.

Comment: Ah ... that's it. I have some external Pods. thanks.

Comment: @LukášHejtmánek No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried Venkatesh's answer but it did not work for me.
I got the error after updating XCode (while it was still open which may have contributed to the problem)

**First**, I deleted my Derived Data folder:
XCode => Preferences => Locations => Double Click on arrow next to path indicating where the Derived Data folder is.
Then "Move to Trash"
I don't think that's what the problem was, but it's amazing how many times this has been an issue for me working on different problems.

**Second**, I 'Quit' the simulator.

**Third**, I 'Quit' XCode.

**Fourth**, I opened up my project in XCode again and then did a Clean and Build (found in the Product menu)

**Fifth**, I ran my project and it worked fine