# Trouble with POD installation: "`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES"

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have issues with POD installation.
In "ProjectName"[Demo] and "ProjectName"[Release] I get the error:
"...target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName-Demo/Pods-ProjectName-Demo.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation"
    [image: Build Settings]

I have set "Always Embed Swift Standard Library" to NO

Edit: I have done the suggested steps in the suggested duplicate post thread, but still got error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's ALWAYS\_EMBED\_SWIFT\_STANDARD\_LIBRARIES with cocoapods , swift 3 and Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570233/whats-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries-with-cocoapods-swift-3-and-xcode)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by doing the following:

> 1.Go into Build Settings
>
> 2.At the top select All and Combined
>
> 3.Under Build Options you should see Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries and it is bold.
>
> 4.Click on it and click delete. It should now be unbolded.
>
> 5.Pod install and the error/errors should go away!

For more details please refer this link.https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5981

Comment: I have done that (see image in question) but it still gives errors.

Comment: did you delete before pod installation.?

Comment: No, I deleted after