# With Swift 5 and iOS 12.2+ should I change "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to NO?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Somehow "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" for all of my targets is YES. Probably due to historical development from Swift 1 to 5.
I'm using Xcode 10.2 now, upgraded the targets and my "Swift language version" is 5 for all of them.

Out of interest I created an empty new project with Xcode 10.2 and it is created with "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" as NO for both Debug and Release builds.

I have a feeling that even if I leave it as it is, Apple will strip standard Swift libraries anyway as a part of thinning for iOS 12.2+?

So what's the correct default since swift 5? Any benefits from either keeping it at YES or changing to NO?

[Update] Thanks to Cœur for a comment. It really looks like that one of the CocoaPods versions did it. Project is set to NO, but all the targets using CocoadPods were YES.

Comment: While the default is `NO`, note that if you use a standard CocoaPods integration, some versions (like CocoaPods 1.6.1) may override `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` default value and set it to `YES`. This was made by https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5732

Comment: Thank you for providing the possible cause of this YES value! I do use CocoaPods from the very early versions.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default for new projects is NO and (as far as I know) always has been. I have *never* had "Always embed" set to YES, and my projects have always worked just fine. So unless there is some really good reason why this was YES, it probably shouldn't have been.

Note that the libraries are stripped out only if you are building against the 12.2 SDK and going onto a machine with 12.2 (or later). The libraries are still needed to run on a 12.1 or earlier machine.

Comment: This setting only makes a difference if your app is pure Objective-C and is using some Swift frameworks: in that case, you would want it to `YES`.

Comment: Marking this as an answer. Plus comment from Cœur makes it probably 100% covered with when YES is needed.

Comment: @Cœur I don't get the point why does pure Objective-C app which wants to use some Swift frameworks or libraries need to set this to `YES`?

Comment: @RaviRaj because in the old times, some Swift standard libraries were not shipped in iOS due to the lack of ABI stability? And so, without those libs, your Swift dependencies wouldn't work. Not too sure about recent iOS releases.

Answer (score 5):

I came here because I've updated my development environment to :

XCode 10.2
iOS 12.2
WatchOS 5.1.3

**And my apps refused to even start on the watch**, with a single message to console, saying library image not found. (using Swift4 build setting)

Setting "always embed" to on makes the app install process incredibly slow on the watch.

I updated the project to use Swift5, now the app at least starts up again.

Answer (score 0):

FYI

If you set true for ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES on the target framework, you will probably receive `ERROR ITMS-90206: Invalid Bundle.`

In my case, I set true for target that is App / Unit Tests / UI Tests.

Answer (score -3):

If you set `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`  `NO` your app may lead to crash while open with iOS 12.1 and lower version.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. All of my targets are now on NO and all of my apps support iOS 9 to 14. Built on iOS 14.1 SDK now, there are no problems whatsoever related to this being NO.

Comment: That might be true. I'll update the answer if I identify it. thanks

Comment: I am late.. but try this out.. "otool -L <your_app> or <.framework file>". See if the swift libs are referenced from @rpath like this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1881/_index.html