# Mapbox Geocoder framework not found

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mkreversegeocoder, mapbox-ios

My project is build in Objective c.
My podfile is as below:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Traget1' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'GooglePlaces'

  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.1'
  pod 'MapboxGeocoder.swift', '~> 0.11'


end

target 'Traget2' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'GooglePlaces'

  pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.1'


end
```

I have $(inherited) set as the framework search path but whenever I try to build the app it shows me the error ld: framework not found MapboxGeocoder

Comment: Have you set the Command Line Tools in Preferencess - Locations?

Comment: Yes that has been set

Comment: In the pod [readme](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxGeocoder.swift), it says  `For Objective-C targets, it may be necessary to enable the ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES build setting`. Have you tried enabling this? How to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41570345/3241041

Comment: Yes Thats enabled