# Target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting warning in Xcode 12.5 and Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, xcode12, xcode12.5

```
[!] The `SampleUITests [Prod]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` 
build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Sample-SampleUITests/Pods-Sample-SampleUITests.prod.xcconfig'. 
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I am getting the above warning when i try to create a new xcode project and add cocoa pods into the project. I already tried the solutions mentioned in [What's ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES with CocoaPods, Swift 3 and Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570233/whats-always-embed-swift-standard-libraries-with-cocoapods-swift-3-and-xcode-8) but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In some Xcode versions(in my case 12.2), when we create a new project with tests included, Xcode sets the "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" for tests and UITests to **Yes** and it would be shown in **Bold text**, which indicates its overridden

To confirm this,
check in your project's build settings and target's build settings if the "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" setting has been modified by Xcode.
Typically it should appear like this in Normal text (not bold) meaning its not modified.
[Non modified build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02zCc.png)
Certain versions of Xcode modifies this setting and hence it would appear in **Bold text**
[modified build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scAj1.png)

To resolve this,

1. Go to the project's **Pbxproj** file (open in VSCode or any editor)
2. Search and remove all mentions
   of ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
3. On doing so, the project
   would take default settings for
   ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.

Try pod install/pod update now and the build setting warning should no longer occur.

Comment: Does "project's Pbxproj file" apply to both the **main** `project.pbxproj` and the **cocoapods** `project.pbxproj`? Is it possible to over-remove the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` mentions?