# Unable to do pod update after uninstalling the pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have added firebase crashlytics pod in my project. After adding, my project shows "No Such Module" for already installed third party libraries like Alamofire, Expandablecells etc.

I have tried to solve this by setting framework search path, clean derived data but nothing worked.

Then I removed pod and tried to install it again, then it is showing.
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target.

Now I am unable to update anything on my project. and it is again showing the same error. 
I have restarted my machine. Update it to high sierra. 
Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks
I checked this url 
[- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target. CocoaPod Swift3 pod update error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599454/use-the-inherited-flag-or-remove-the-build-settings-from-the-target-c)

[image: in terminal]

In project
[image: Poject structure.]
[image: Pod file screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a version of `cocoapods` that refers to Ruby 2.0 - the first line of your `pod` script is

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
```

AFAIK this version of ruby is no longer present in High Sierra.

Run `sudo gem install cocoapods`, after this, this line should be

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Please share where I write this line? in pod file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "where"... Just run `sudo gem install cocoapods`  in a terminal.

Comment: xcodeproj's executable "xcodeproj" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/xcodeproj
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  

What should I do?

Comment: Yes, since you want to use the new version.

Comment: Done installing documentation for concurrent-ruby, i18n, thread_safe, tzinfo, activesupport, nap, fuzzy_match, cocoapods-core, claide, cocoapods-deintegrate, cocoapods-downloader, cocoapods-plugins, cocoapods-search, cocoapods-stats, netrc, cocoapods-trunk, cocoapods-try, molinillo, atomos, CFPropertyList, colored2, nanaimo, xcodeproj, escape, fourflusher, gh_inspector, ruby-macho, cocoapods after 19 seconds
28 gems installed

Comment: but still getting same error when build the project.

Comment: Try `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`

Comment: This is a known issue with Cocoapods: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6898

Comment: I have tried all solutions and nothing has worked for me. Please please suggest how can I solve it?

in terminal showing this msg 
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.