# pod install / update on iOS11 with Xcode12.2

Tags: error-handling, cocoapods, ios11, xcode12

I am getting the below mentioned error when trying to install pod after updating xcode12.2 on macOs11.0.

```
 [!] The `Myproject-User-iOSUITests [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Myproject-User-iOS-DipDap-User-iOSUITests/Pods-Myproject-User-iOS-DipDap-User-iOSUITests.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
        - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
        - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Myproject-User-iOSUITests [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Myproject-User-iOS-DipDap-User-iOSUITests/Pods-DipDap-User-iOS-Myproject-User-iOSUITests.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I searched for the error and got some results, changed the values as per the specified link,

[Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599454/use-the-inherited-flag-or-remove-the-build-settings-from-the-target-c)

But still getting the same error and my pod frameworks not updated

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

- Project Target -> building settings -> ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES, ->  Value type is Boolean, click on the other, change the value to $(inherited)
- pod install/ pod update.

It will work.. :)