# Framework 'Pods_Runner' not found

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to run the flutter app but getting this error

[same issue here but none helped](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50711)

```
Launching lib/main_dev.dart on iPhone 15 in debug mode...
main_dev.dart:1
Upgrading Pods-Runner-frameworks.sh
Xcode build done.                                           54.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Framework 'Pods_Runner' not found

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

versions

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-TR)
    • Flutter version 3.10.5 on channel stable at /Users/yarenalbayrak/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 796c8ef792 (4 months ago), 2023-06-13 15:51:02 -0700
    • Engine revision 45f6e00911
    • Dart version 3.0.5
    • DevTools version 2.23.1
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15A240d
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3
```

[image: It creates pods_runner file every run]
It creates pods_runner file every run.

My part of the Podfile looks like this. When I delete use_frameworks! line to not create the file whenever it runs I get some other problems.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '14.0'

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

 flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to delete Podfile.lock inside the iOS folder and then run the pod install command?

Comment: Sure, didn't help

Comment: The same happens for me, but only when I run the app on a real iOS device. Works fine when run on a simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599454/use-the-inherited-flag-or-remove-the-build-settings-from-the-target-c), when I run pod install it was giving me warnings

`Runner [Debug-dev]` target overrides the `EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]`

I went to Target -> Build Settings and searched for EXCLUDED_ARCHS and changed the values to $(inherited)

Answer (score 18):

1. delete `Podfile`
2. run `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` in your Flutter program, then `Podfile` will be generated
3. In new `Podfile`, adjust `platform` to 14.0 and Uncomment that line
4. run `pod install` in your iOS program

everything will be ok

Comment: Tried your solution exactly but didn't help either.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I solved the problem. Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50711#issuecomment-586318357):

> Open XCode > [Build Phases] > [Link Binary WIth Libraries].
>
> remove `Pod_Runner.framework`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have changed platform in ios/Podfile, don't forget to update iOS Deployment Target in Pods target.

I'm quoting an answer from the github link which had helped me in the past-> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50711#issuecomment-770397291

```
The problem for me ended up being that the platform :ios, '12.0' was a higher iOS version than the targets specified in the XCode projects. Once I changed the target iOS in the XCode projects, it built. In XCode 11, that's at [Project Navigator button] -> Runner top level blue icon -> General -> Deployment Info -> Target.
```

Comment: Tried that too, didn't help. I added more detail about the question.